# Displaying Associated Image with Gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I'm using Gmaps4rails to display a map of properties.

The properties model has an associating photo model. Does anybody know how I could implement an associated photo into an info window. My info window method at the moment is as below.

```
def gmaps4rails_infowindow
    "<strong> #{self.reference} </strong><br /> #{self.bedrooms} bedroom #{self.p_type}<br /> <a href='http://www.crescentlettings.co.uk/properties/#{id}'>See more details</a> " 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty straight:

```
def gmaps4rails_infowindow
  "<img src='#{self.photo.url}'><strong> #{self.reference} </strong><br /> #{self.bedrooms} bedroom #{self.p_type}<br /> <a href='http://www.crescentlettings.co.uk/properties/#{id}'>See more details</a> " 
end
```